Specifying properties of a function as assumptions
I am trying to simplify expressions involving a function $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ which satisfies
$$f(-z) = -f(z), \quad f(z^*) = f(z)^*, \quad \forall z \in \mathbb C.$$
I do not want to specify any explicit form for $f$, but I want to tell the Simplify function that it can use the above properties. However, I can't quite get it to work.
As a minimal example of my problem consider the following input:
expr = a f[x - y\[Conjugate]] + b f[y - x\[Conjugate]]\[Conjugate];
asmp = {ForAll[z, f[-z] == -f[z]], 
   ForAll[z, f[z\[Conjugate]] == f[z]\[Conjugate]]};
Simplify[expr, asmp]

I would have hoped to get something like the output
(a - b) f[x - Conjugate[y]]

but instead I get
b Conjugate[f[y - Conjugate[x]]] + a f[x - Conjugate[y]]

What am I doing wrong, and what is the correct way to specify properties like these?
P.S. I am using Mathematica 12.1.

For further context, the actual expression I am trying to simplify is a monster of the following calibre ($\alpha$ is the actual name of the function previously referred to as $f$):


What about Simplify[-f[-x] f[x], Assumptions -> f[-x] == -f[x]] it gives f[x]^2.

Use TagSetDelayed, e.g., f /: f[-z_] := -f[z]; along wth f[z_?Negative] := -f[-z]

@yarchik That only works on the minimal example above, but not on the actual problem, since it relies on the argument litterally being x. I want it to work for arbitrary arguments, since it is a property of the function.

Please, update your example to reflect your actual problem.

@BobHanlon I get wrong answer with your code for Simplify[-f[-5 + a] f[a - 5]], namely -f[-5 + a]^2. My suggestion also does not work.

Please edit your post to include one or a few examples that are big enough, but not HUGE, to demonstrate exactly the problems that you are having with all the suggested fixes.

@Bill All right, done.

@yarchik - The simplification after using TagSetDelayed is -f[-5 + a]  f[a - 5] /. a -> y + 5 /. y -> a - 5

I can't scrape that fragment of your image off the screen and paste it into Mathematica and try any of the tricks that I know to see if they will work on your problem.  That was why I asked for one or a few examples big enough, but not HUGE.

I usually implement such identities via TransformationFunctions. In this case, neither Simplify nor FullSimplify would apply all the combinations of the identities, so I supplied various combinations of them. The Block[..] ones apply an identity to the first instance of f[] only. At one point, I thought I might need them all. Then I hit on the right combinations.  We need either the first or the third one, but not all three. So who knows in the actual problem which may be needed.  Hence I will leave them all in.
expr = a  f[x - y\[Conjugate]] + b  f[y - x\[Conjugate]]\[Conjugate];
Simplify[expr
 , TransformationFunctions -> {
   Automatic
   (*,Replace[#,f[z_]:>-f[-z]]&,Replace[#,f[z_]:>f[z\[Conjugate]]\[Conjugate]]&*)
   , Simplify[# /. f[z_] :> f[z\[Conjugate]]\[Conjugate]] &
   , Simplify[# /. f[z_] :> -f[-z]] &
   , Simplify[# /. f[z_] :> -f[-z\[Conjugate]]\[Conjugate]] &
   , Simplify@
     Block[{n = 0}, # /. f[z_] :> If[++n <= 1, -f[-z], f[z]]] &
   , Simplify@
     Block[{n = 0}, # /. 
       f[z_] :> If[++n <= 1, f[z\[Conjugate]]\[Conjugate], f[z]]] &
   , Simplify@
     Block[{n = 0}, # /. 
       f[z_] :> If[++n <= 1, -f[-z\[Conjugate]]\[Conjugate], f[z]]] &
   }]

(*  (a - b) f[x - Conjugate[y]]  *)

Update: Alternatives
Another way is to use a ComplexityFunction that scores a chosen form of f[x - Conjugate[y]] (or forms if there are arguments that cannot be reduced to a single form):
Simplify[expr
 , TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic
   , ReplaceAll[f[z_] :> f[z\[Conjugate]]\[Conjugate]], 
   ReplaceAll[f[z_] :> -f[-z]]}
 , ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] - 
     5 Count[#, f[x - y\[Conjugate]], Infinity] &)]

Or possible differentiating some aspect of a desired argument or arguments, although it can be tricky to solve problem Y by solving an indirectly related problem X. These complexity functions work on the example input:
ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] - 
    5 Count[#, -Conjugate[y], Infinity] &)
ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
    5 Count[#, _Conjugate, Infinity] - 
    5 Count[#, -Conjugate[_], Infinity] &)


Thank you for your answer. I am surprised that things like these seem to require so much trial and error, but maybe I am overestimating the power of the algorithms used by Simplify. In the end I had more luck defining replacement rules and using ReplaceRepeated.
